# What is difference between IList and IList<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

Definition of `List<T>` in .net shows it implement various interfaces.

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

What changes interfaces with and without `T` brings in `IList` i.e. if one of my class implement `IList<T>` and not `IList`, then can I use it as my custom collection class or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason that `List<T>` implements both `IList<T>` and `IList` is to make it usable anywhere your code is assuming an `IList`. This will make it more easier to make a transition to the generic `IList<T>` since it is the more appropriate one. Also, if you have a .net 1.1 or earlier code that you would like to reuse even though your class is implemented in a .net 2.0 or later assembly it will make it possible.

Answer (score 6):

In a `IList<T>` you can only put the defined(T) type of object in and a IList can contain diffrent types of objects

This code below will not complie because of the AdressInformation is not an valid object in customers List

```
IList<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
customers.Add(new Customer());
customers.Add(new AdressInformation());
```

This code will compile but cast an exception in runtime

```
IList customers = new List<Customer>();
customers.Add(new Customer());
customers.Add(new AdressInformation());
```

Comment: If I use         IList customer = new List<Customer>() and after that customer.Add("1") it should work but still it gives me error(at run time). As per definition as it is implementing IList without T also, so it should work when I Add any value as object in IList.

Comment: That would compile because the customer variabel is not generic.

Comment: @user1888859 you need to cast your IList<Customer> to IList if you want the compile to let you add "1" like this ((IList)myGenericList).Add("1")

Comment: It is working at compile time but at run time giving error               IList<Custome> objIListCustomer= new List<Custome>();
            IList obj = (IList)objIListCustomer;

            obj.Add("1");      It is showing error value as 1 can't use in generic collection

Comment: of course it fails at runtime... that's the whole point with generics! why on earth shouldn't it fail - you constrained the list to only hold Customer instances, so there would be no truth back in the world if you were suddenly allowed to add strings.

Comment: @PauliØsterø - I believe that the whole point of generics is that you will fail on compile time rather than on runtime.

Comment: `IList` is only an interface, not a base class implementation.  The only thing it forces is that the class implements that public interface.  `List<T>` does implement that interface, so it can be cast to `IList`.  Just because its particular implementation of the interface throws an exception when it is called with an invalid parameter doesn't mean that it doesn't implement the interface.  The interface doesn't specify when the class implementing it can or cannot throw an exception.

Comment: @Ikaso failing to compile is no guarantee that it will work at runtime. You can ie. use reflection to call the Add-method passing integers to a IList<string> and the compiler wouldn't know that it wasn't legal. This Blog Post is an eye-opener for many who thinks that compiling means testing the program for flaws http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2009-09/09-compiling_is_not_a_very_useful_test

Comment: @PauliØsterø - that is true that a non failing compilation is no guarantee for runtime. But claiming that the whole point of the generics is to catch errors on runtime is simply not true. The same thing will happen if you store in .net 1.1 ArrayList a list of ints and then try to cast them to a string. It is a feature of the CLR and not a feature of generics.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:**

What is the difference between `IList` and `IList<T>`?

**Answer:**

Both `IList` and `IList<T>` are interfaces, but `IList` is not generic and it is both member of and belongs to the `System.Collections` namespace while `IList<T>` is generic and it is both member of and belongs to the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Also `System.Collections.IList` is simply both equivalent and identical to `System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>` as well.

Since `object`, in C#, can be anything and every type that can be used in the generic type `T` , inside the angle brackets, extends `object`, this means that `System.Collections.IList` and `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>` have the same expressive power.

This also says that all the tasks that can be done with the help of `System.Collections.IList` interface, these tasks can also be done with the help of `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>` interface.

If so then what to prefer: `System.Collections.IList` or `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`?

While `System.Collections.IList` is shorter and requires less typing, `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>` is still much more both better and recommended, because it makes your code all more precise, accurate, exact, correct, strict, informative, explanatory, detailed, elaborate, itemized, particularized, expressive, clear, readable and legible and if the programmer makes any mistake in using the generic interface, probably that compilation will fail and the programmer will immediately know and understand what he/she did wrong, correct the errors and the customer may encounter less bugs in the application.

But using the non generic interface improperly may create unknown bugs that throw cast failure exceptions in the application that the customer may find, make him/her unsatisfied, report to the developers about these bugs and may also demand/require/initiate a refund.

For an example:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IList<int> list = GetSomeListOfIntegers();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add("four");
list.Add(5);
```

The above code doesn't compile because of the line `list.Add("four");`.

The error says, more or less, that the argument must be `int`, but it was `string`.

This is good to see errors of compiler and correct all of them before building the application. This way, the customer won't encounter unnecessary bugs in the application and remain satisfied.

But if the programmer does not change the line `list.Add("four");`, that causes the compiler to fail, but instead replaces `System.Collections.Generic.IList<int>` by `System.Collections.IList` and modifies the method `GetSomeListOfIntegers` to return an instance of `System.Collections.IList` instead of an instance of `System.Collections.Generic.IList<int>`

Then the code compiles successfully, but when `list.Add("four");` is executed, a cast failure exception is thrown and then the application stops executing and terminates.

And who knows which customer will find this bug if all the programmers and developers will fail to find this bug.

This is the reason why all the generic classes and interfaces, including `IList<T>`, of the namespace `System.Collections.Generic` are much better than all the classes and interfaces, including `IList`, of the namespace `System.Collections` and `System.Collections.Generic` should be the recommended namespace **in general**.

Historically the namespace `System.Collections` and all the classes and interfaces defined in this namespace, including the interface `IList`, were exist before the namespace `System.Collections.Generic` and all it's classes and interfaces including the `IList<T>` generic interface.

The namespace `System.Collections.Generic` and all it's classes and interfaces were introduced in a later version of the .NET Framework of Microsoft.