# How can I iterate over an List<T> to access values when T is returned from a Factory and unknown

Tags: c#, list, factory-pattern

Please forgive me if the title is not worded correctly.

I am retrieving data from database tables for various devices and building a list. Different devices could have the same properties and will definitely have some properties that differ, So I am using a Factory Pattern to create whichever is needed at run time.

Factory class:

```
public interface IImportModel
{
    IList CreateImportList(SqlDataReader reader);
}
```

And Concrete class:

```
public class Device1ImportModel : IImportModel
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string PartA { get; set; }

    public IList CreateImportList(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        Device1ImportModel linkedItem = new Device1ImportModel();

        List<Device1ImportModel> importList = new List<Device1ImportModel>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            linkedItem = new Device1ImportModel();

            linkedItem.SerialNumber = reader["SerialNo"].ToString();
            linkedItem.PartA = reader["PartA"].ToString();

            importList.Add(linkedItem);
        }

        return importList;
    }
}
```

I create the device from the factory:

```
importModel = ImportModelFactory.CreateImportModel("Device1");
```

Now when I want to iterate over the importModel, I receive a compile time error on the line where I attempt to access item.SerialNumber

```
foreach (var item in importList)                  
{
      string number = item.SerialNumber;
}
```

The error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'SerialNumber' and no extension method 'SerialNumber' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.

If I place a breakpoint and hover over item variable, I can see the properties and value.

I tried using dynamic instead of var, but then later in my code I can no longer use Linq or Lambda queries.

1. How can I access the values?
2. Can I convert the IList to List perhaps using Reflection?

Edit 1

Added Code for CreateImportModel:

```
static public IImportModel CreateImportModel(DeviceType device)
{
    switch (device)
    {
        case DeviceType.Device1:
            return new Device1ImportModel();

        case DeviceType.Device2:
            return new DeviceImportModel();

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the source code for `CreateImportModel`.

Comment: Do all device types have `SerialNumber`?

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot change your method's signature, you can use:

```
foreach (var item in importList.Cast<Device1ImportModel>())                  
{
    string number = item.SerialNumber;
}
```

This will throw an exception, however, if there will be an object in the `importList` collection that is not a `Device1ImportModel` or its derived class.

If you're not sure that all objects in the list are of that type and want to avoid exceptions, use this apporach:

```
foreach (var item in importList.OfType<Device1ImportModel>())                  
{
    string number = item.SerialNumber;
}
```

Comment: i do not know beforehand which class to call.

Comment: @Neill, if you don't know which class to expect, how can you be sure that there will be a `SerialNumber` property? Your problem has no solution then.

Comment: There are certain properties that all classes will always have. SerialNumber is one of them.

Comment: @Neil, then just extract all of these properties into an interface `ICommonProperties` and do `importList.Cast<ICommonProperties>()`.

Comment: @Neill Have you considered adding `SerialNumber` to `IImportModel`?

Comment: I ended up just using a separate class to hold all the properties, whether each other concrete class uses them or not. Its not ideal but works. I would have preferred relying on each concrete class to be responsible for it's own properties though.

Answer (score 2):

Change `IList` to `List<Device1ImportModel>` (or `IList<Device1ImportModel>` or `IReadOnlyList<Device1ImportModel>`).

```
public List<Device1ImportModel> CreateImportList(SqlDataReader reader)
```

[`IList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002674/what-is-difference-between-ilist-and-ilistt) is an older interface (pre-generics) and thus if you use `IList` (rather than `IList<Device1ImportModel`) then the compiler / runtime has no notion of the `Type` of your data (i.e. it treats it as `object`), thus:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'SerialNumber' and no
>   extension method 'SerialNumber' accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found.

You may also need to change the interface to:

```
public interface IImportModel<T>
{
    List<T> CreateImportList(SqlDataReader reader);
}
```

and the class to:

```
public class Device1ImportModel : IImportModel<Device1ImportModel>
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string PartA { get; set; }

    public List<Device1ImportModel> CreateImportList(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
```

You likely also want to change `CreateImportModel` so instead of calling it like:

```
ImportModelFactory.CreateImportModel("Device1");
```

you instead call it like:

```
ImportModelFactory.CreateImportModel<Device1ImportModel>();
```

so that a concrete `Device1ImportModel` is returned (and thus `SerialNumber` is accessible).

Comment: That doesn't work because my interface is set to  IList CreateImportList(SqlDataReader reader); I have more than one concrete class and won't know ahead of time which one is being called....

Comment: @Neill Then iterating over that list and expecting it to have a property found in only one of the concrete types is a design flaw. If all concrete types have a `SerialNumber` then make it part of the interface and use `List<IImportModel>`.

Comment: @mjwills - Unfortunately I don't know ahead of time which class to use. ImportModelFactory.CreateImportModel<Device1ImportModel>();

Comment: How did you know to pass "Device1" in?

Comment: Its a string from a drop down that calls the CreateImportModel method

Comment: Apologies, CreateImportModel() uses an enum to switch

Comment: How should I change the CreateImportModel method?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a separate class to hold all the properties, whether each other concrete class uses them or not.

Its not ideal but works.

I would have preferred relying on each concrete class to be responsible for it's own properties though.